# Computing the difference of the sum of the values of a table daily

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `communities` that tells me how many times different pages were shared online.

```
CREATE TABLE communities
    (`community_id` int, `shares_copylink` int, `shares_email` int, `shares_facebook` int, `shares_messenger` int, `shares_pinterest` int, `shares_twitter` int, `shares_whatsapp` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO communities
    (`community_id`, `shares_copylink`, `shares_email`, `shares_facebook`, `shares_messenger`, `shares_pinterest`, `shares_twitter`, `shares_whatsapp`)
VALUES
    (1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (2, 2, 2, 196, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (3, 8, 20, 0, 8, 0, 0, 12),
    (6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (7, 0, 0, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (8, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
    (9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (12, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1),
    (14, 1, 1, 11, 0, 0, 0, 3),
    (16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (59, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (60, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (61, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (62, 2, 3, 28, 0, 0, 0, 9),
    (65, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (66, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (67, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (68, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (69, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (70, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (71, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (72, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (73, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (74, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (75, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (76, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (77, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (78, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (79, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (80, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (81, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (82, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (83, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (84, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (85, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (86, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (87, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (88, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (89, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (90, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (91, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (93, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (94, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (95, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (96, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (97, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (98, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (99, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (103, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (104, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 4),
    (105, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (106, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (107, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (108, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (109, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (110, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (111, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (142, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (143, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (145, 0, 1, 39, 1, 0, 0, 4),
    (146, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (147, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    (148, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
;
```

I want to start a query that would run every day and would insert in a table how many shares have occures today.

So I started with creating a table with the number of queries up to today:

```
CREATE TABLE shares (Date date, Shares int);

INSERT INTO
`shares` (`Date`, `Shares`)
SELECT
  CURDATE() as date,
  SUM(shares_copylink) + SUM(shares_email) + SUM(shares_facebook) + SUM(shares_messenger) + SUM(shares_pinterest) + SUM(shares_twitter) + SUM(shares_whatsapp) AS total
  FROM communities
```

I now need to run a query that does the difference between the sum of all `shares*` columns of communities (which would be updated) and the value stored in `shares`. I will run it for every day D+1 and insert the results in `shares` so it should always be equal to the sum of `shares*` columns in communities.

I tried:

```
SELECT CURDATE(), all_shares - all_shares_but_today AS daily_shares FROM
 (
    (
      SUM(shares_copylink) + SUM(shares_email) + SUM(shares_facebook) + SUM(shares_messenger) + SUM(shares_pinterest) + SUM(shares_twitter) + SUM(shares_whatsapp)
    ) AS all_shares FROM communities,
   (
     SUM(`Shares`)
   ) AS all_shares_but_today)
```

But it returns:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SUM(shares_copylink) + SUM(shares_email) + SUM(shares_facebook) + SUM(shares_mes' at line 4

I also tried something in [this Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/001e83/34/0) but it creates a cartesian product.

I'm using MySQL 5.7

Comment: I don't see a `GROUP BY` on your aggregating query

Comment: I would suggest just putting the cumulative value in.  You can use `lag()` on the table to get the difference if that is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try below, I'm not sure if this is what you need.

```
    SELECT CURDATE(), 
(
  (
  SELECT 
  (SUM(shares_copylink) 
  + SUM(shares_email)
  + SUM(shares_facebook) 
  + SUM(shares_messenger)
  + SUM(shares_pinterest) 
  + SUM(shares_twitter) 
  + SUM(shares_whatsapp)) as sumval
  FROM communities
  ) - SUM(`Shares`)

) AS daily_shares
FROM shares
```